# SUM of textboxes values using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text boxes with same class name price. i used jquery loop to calculate the sum of numbers but i  give undefiend error in alert box here is my code. Thanx

```
<input type="text" class="price" name="amount" onblur="checknumber()" />
<input type="text" class="price" name="amount" onblur="checknumber()" />
<input type="text" class="price" name="amount" onblur="checknumber()" />
<input type="text" class="price" name="amount" onblur="checknumber()" />
function checknumber()
{
                var sum= 0; 
             $('.price').each(function() {

            sum += Number($(this).val());

              });

        alert(sum);

}
```

Comment: `alert(sum);` no need for `.value`.

Comment: ok dear but it cannot calculate the sum its answer is 0 now

Comment: alert the variable sum only.

Comment: And why are you casting value to `Number`? Can't you just use `parseInt` for example?

Comment: yes i alert sum only but it give 0 answer

Comment: how come you are getting 0. see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/72tQ9/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sum.value` would refer to `sum` as though it were a reference to an input dom element. Just use `alert(sum)` to alert the value of the variable `sum`.

Please also note that the use of inline js (onblur in your html) is bad practice and `console.log` is a lot more convenient for debugging (no annoying pop-up). Refactor like this: **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/egevEsA/2/edit)**

```
<input type="text" class="price" name="amount" />
<input type="text" class="price" name="amount" />
<input type="text" class="price" name="amount"/>
<input type="text" class="price" name="amount" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$prices = $('.price');
$prices.blur(function() {
  var sum= 0; 
  $prices.each(function() {
    sum += Number($(this).val());
  });
  console.log(sum);
});
```

Read these results for info on the evil of inline js: https://www.google.com/search?q=Why+is+inline+js+bad%3F

Comment: dear but it cannot calculate the sum of text boxes it give 0 answer

Comment: sorry dear but my pints is less than 15. and somebody also click -1. Dear i cannot understand why people click -1. New programmer cannot know programming and make some mistake it does not means u discourge it.